# Integer division through multiplication by reciprocal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Please help me to understand (prove) why the following statement is true.

For any natural number $w > 0$ and divisor $b \in \left[ 1, 2^w \right)$, if we define a natural number $inv(b)$ such that

$$
2^w - b \leq b \cdot \mathrm{inv}(b) < 2^w
$$

then for any natural dividend $a \in \left[ 0, 2^w \right)$ and quotient $q = \left \lfloor  a/b \right \rfloor$ it follows that
$$
q - 1 \leq \left \lfloor \frac{a \cdot inv(b)}{2^w} \right \rfloor \leq q.
$$

Comment: Isn't $b.inv(b)$ not the same thing as 1? Seems a bit redundant.

Comment: No because $\mathrm{inv}(b)$ is a natural number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything in sight is positive we have, from your first inequality, that

$$\frac{a}{b} - \frac{a}{2^w} \leq \frac{a\cdot \mathrm{inv}(b)}{2^w} < \frac{a}{b}.$$

Also note that if $x\leq y$, $\lfloor x\rfloor \leq \lfloor y \rfloor$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Okay. The floor function $\left \lfloor  \right \rfloor$ changes $<$ relation to the $\leq$ on the right side of inequality. Now it seems obvious to me, but what about the left-hand side? How the term $a/2^w$ has become 1? I understand that $a/2^w \in \left[0, 1 \right)$ and Intuitively I realize that $\left \lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right \rfloor - 1 \leq \left \lfloor \frac{a}{b} - \frac{a}{2^w} \right \rfloor$ but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @Menzoda Can you prove that $\lfloor x + y \rfloor \geq \lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor$? (Hint: split $x$ and $y$ into real and fractional parts)

Comment: I think i've got it! We have $\left \lfloor x + y \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor x_i + x_f + y_i + y_f \right \rfloor = x_i + y_i + \left \lfloor x_f + y_f \right \rfloor$. At the same time $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor x_i + x_f \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y_i + y_f \right \rfloor = x_i + y_i$. So it's clear that $x_i + y_i + \left \lfloor x_f + y_f \right \rfloor\geq  x_i + y_i$.

Comment: Using this we have $\left \lfloor \frac{a}{b} - \frac{a}{2^w} \right \rfloor \geq \left \lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor -\frac{a}{2^w} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right \rfloor - 1$ Yeehaw! Thanks dude!